# My MacBook Pro (2019) background keeps going black every 4-7 seconds

Tags: macos, mac, macos-bigsur

My MacBook pro background keeps going black every 4-7 seconds. When it goes black, the dock at the bottom slides out and then slides back up when the screen goes to the regular background. Something to keep in mind is that only the background goes black. Any application or software I have open stays fine.

Something else I have noticed is that I got a process named ifilogin-helper that starts at about 200mb of ram and continuously grows. The highest it has gone without a restart has been 16GB. I'm not super knowledgeable on macOS but that doesn't seem right.

When did all of this start happening? I think this might be all related to a background image change I did (However I've changed that all around to every possible thing and it still does it) or it might be because it downloaded macOS Monterey? But this wouldn't make any sense because I cannot upgrade my machine anyways (this is my works computer and Monterey is blocked).

After the screen goes black, if I had something minimized, it will bring it back up. Note that none of this happens on the login screen at all and does happen on the computers screen as well as any external monitors.

I've tried anything I can find on the web and have had no luck. It does the same thing on safe mode, I cleared the ram, smc, turned off true tone, changed to many backgrounds, nothing. Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

I noticed the following in the console logs:

batteryImage = <CGImage 0x7fa74ac3e8e0> (DP) <<CGColorSpace 0x7fa74c00d020> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)> width = 28, height = 14, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 128  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGImageByteOrder32Little  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked  is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes

There are a ton of those in the logs. So I unplugged the power and noticed that the icon still shows it as plugged in and 100%. I restarted my mac with the cable unplugged and in the login screen, it shows the actual percentage and the icon displays as unplugged.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Finder crashing and restarting. Check for crash logs.

Comment: @Spiff close, it's the Dock that's crashing. Might be due to OP's wallpaper, but it seems more likely that it has something to do with the image for the battery (given the log outputs). I've never seen a process named " ifilogin-helper" nor can I figure it what it would stand for.

Comment: @At0mic He probably typo'd "efilogin-helper". Apparently it has some weird interaction with desktop pictures? And possibly with FileVault? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958896/efilogin-helper-running-continuously-at-high-cpu-on-macbook-pro